# php basic array question

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine

I'm having trouble getting the value of the last insert Id from doctrine.  I did a bit of research and I found that the following should work:

```
//save the store now
$store = new Store();
$store->url = $this->form_validation->set_value('website');
$store->save();
$store_id = $store->identifier();

echo print_r($store->identifier());
```

Returns

```
Array ( [id] => 1000034 )
```

How do I pull just the value (1000034) out of the array and set it in a variable that I can use elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$store_id` is an associative array with a single value keyed by "id" so:

```
$id = $store_id['id'];
```